# C# JsonConverter for Type Dictionary<int, double> where double value can be 'Infinity'

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I am getting some data from an api that returns an object that has a property of `Type` `Dictionary<int, double?>?` in JSON. The issue is that some times the JSON will pass back `Infinity` in the `double` property so my deserialize fails trying to convert `Infinity` to `double`. I am trying to write a `JsonConverter` to handle this but I dont know how to check if the `double` is `Infinity`. This is what I have so far.

```
internal class InfinityDictionaryToNullJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<int, double?>?>
{
    public override Dictionary<int, double?>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert,JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            Type keyType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Type valueType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[1];

            if (reader.GetString().Contains("Infinity"))
            {
                return new Dictionary<int, double?> { { 0, 0 } };
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var test = reader.GetString();
        }

        return new Dictionary<int, double?> { { 0, 0 } };
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer,Dictionary<int, double?>? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

I can see that the `reader.TokenType` is `JsonTokenType.StartObject` but the next step is what I need help with. I would like to check if the `double` is `Infinity`, and if it is set it to `default(double?)` or even just 0.

An example of the data is here:

```json
{
  "TeamRanks": {
    "0": "Infinity",
    "1": "1757.739122974623"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a converter.  You may deserialize that JSON by setting [`NumberHandling`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.numberhandling?view=net-6.0) to `JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals` and `JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString`:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    NumberHandling = 
        JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals 
        | JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
};
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(json, options);
```

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-6.0), this flag has the following possible values:

> | Flag | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | `Strict` | [The default.] Numbers will only be read from Number tokens and will only be written as JSON numbers (without quotes). |
> | `AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals` | The "NaN", "Infinity", and "-Infinity" String tokens can be read as floating-point constants, and the Single and Double values for these constants will be written as their corresponding JSON string representations. |
> | `AllowReadingFromString` | Numbers can be read from String tokens. Does not prevent numbers from being read from Number token. |
> | `WriteAsString` | Numbers will be written as JSON strings (with quotes), not as JSON numbers. |

If you would prefer to replace the `Infinity` values with `null` you could do that in an [`IJsonOnDeserialized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.ijsonondeserialized?view=net-6.0) callback:

```
public class Model : IJsonOnDeserialized
{
    public Dictionary<int, double?>? TeamRanks { get; set; } = new ();
    
    public void OnDeserialized()
    {
        if (TeamRanks != null)
            foreach (var pair in TeamRanks.Where(p => p.Value != null && !double.IsFinite(p.Value.Value)).ToList())
                TeamRanks[pair.Key] = null;
    }
}
```

However, [`Double.PositiveInfinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.positiveinfinity) is a perfectly valid value for a c# `double` that can be checked for directly or by using [`!Double.IsFinite(value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.isfinite) so you might just leave the values as-is.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kesH9X).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is

```
json = json.Replace("\"Infinity\"", "null");

//or
json = json.Replace("\"Infinity\"", "\""+ default(double).ToString()+"\"");  // "0"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly parse "Infinity, -Infinity, Nan" to double using the following overload of parse:

```
Double.Parse(reader.GetString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```